# I earned 100 reputation because I can be trusted on other networks

Tags: support

What does this mean? When I went to see if there was any new questions on Scifi & Fantasy I noticed I had earned reputation, so when i clicked the symbol where it shows how you earn't reputation it said the following...

> You have earned a bonus 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites on the network

What does this mean and how did I earn it. I know it says it all by the quote above but I would like an answer because I don't really understand.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

While different StackExchange sites have different standards and norms, they still share a lot of similar traits. If you know how one site works (how to write a good question, how to give a good answer, the mechanics of up/downvoting, etc), you already have a good head start in fitting into any other StackExchange site.

Due to that, if you have more than 200 rep in *any* StackExchange site, and you link that profile to a new StackExchange site, you automatically get 100 reputation. You've proven you know your way around an SE site, so you get an automatic bump in all sites, allowing you to [do things](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) like post links and images, upvote, write comments, and all other intermediate-level features that brand-new users don't get.

Basically, it means that we trust you.